# CreateSlice's extraReducer action not updating the state

Tags: react-native, react-redux, expo, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

## The Setup

I'm writing a reducer using `createSlice` as such:

```js
export const fetchUserProfile = createAsyncThunk(...)

export const UserProfileSlice = createSlice<UserProfileState | null, SliceCaseReducers<UserProfileState | null>>({
  name: 'UserProfile',
  initialState: null,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchUserProfile.pending, (state, action) => {
      console.log("Fetching user profile...")
    })
    builder.addCase(fetchUserProfile.rejected, (state, action) => {
      // TODO: Handle this properly later.
      console.log('Failed to fetch user profiles: ', action.payload)
    })
    builder.addCase(fetchUserProfile.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      console.log('State was: ', state)
      state = action.payload
      console.log('State is ', state)
    })
  }
})

export default UserProfileSlice.reducer
```

I'm adding the slice's reducer to my root reducer using `combineReducers`, and I'm creating my store as such:

```js
export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

I'm using the state in a component this way:

```js
const user = useAppSelector(state => state.userProfileReducer)
```

## Expected Behaviour

When the `fetchUserProfile.fulfilled` action is dispatched, the state is updated and the component is re-rendered to reflect its data.

## Actual Behaviour

The closure passed to the `builder.addCase(fetchUserProfile.fulfilled,...)` is run (as evidenced by the console outputs), but its result is never reflected in the state as seen by the component.

I'm new to react native and the whole JS ecosystem, so I'm kinda stumped on debugging this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is handled in [Writing Immer Reducers: Mutating and Returning State](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#mutating-and-returning-state).

`state = newValue` does not have any effect. It does not *modify the object in `state`*, but it *throws away the object in `state` and puts some new value into the variable*.

Mutations of the *object in state* can be observed from outside of the function - simply changing the variable can not.

The solution?

Do `return newValue` instead.